# Executing Observables in sequence

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

I am trying implement rxJava in android application and I am trying to wrap my head around this. Here is the scenario i am trying to satisfy:

1. call a web service to get program details
2. call the next web service with data from the first one to determine its live streaming status (none, transcoding, complete, etc)
3. combine and transform the response into an object that gets sent back up the to ui for display.

Ideally, if the call in step 2 contains a response, and it is not complete, this could continually run until such time as that job completes on the backend. But I am taking baby steps here and will tackle that next.

UPDATE: 2015-10-21
This is where I am at so far. I can probably be cleaned up.

```
public Observable<Program> recordedProgram( int chanId, DateTime startTime ) {

  final DvrDataStore dvrDataStore = this.dvrDataStoreFactory.create( chanId, startTime );
  final ContentDataStore contentDataStore = this.contentDataStoreFactory.createMasterBackendDataStore();

  Observable<ProgramEntity> programEntity = dvrDataStore.recordedProgramEntityDetails( chanId, startTime );
  Observable<List<LiveStreamInfoEntity>> liveStreamInfoEntity = programEntity
        .flatMap(recordedProgramEntity -> contentDataStore.liveStreamInfoEntityList(recordedProgramEntity.getFileName()));

  Observable<ProgramEntity> recordedProgramEntity = Observable.zip(programEntity, liveStreamInfoEntity, new Func2<ProgramEntity, List<LiveStreamInfoEntity>, ProgramEntity>() {

      @Override
      public ProgramEntity call(ProgramEntity programEntity, List<LiveStreamInfoEntity> liveStreamInfoEntityList) {

          if (null != liveStreamInfoEntityList && !liveStreamInfoEntityList.isEmpty()) {
              programEntity.setLiveStreamInfoEntity(liveStreamInfoEntityList.get( 0 ) );
          }

          return programEntity;
      }

  });

  return recordedProgramEntity.map(recordedProgram -> 

  this.programEntityDataMapper.transform(recordedProgram));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `.firstObservable.flatmap( ... ) //will have access to first result`
2. `.filter( ... )  //will filter out the ones that dont fit your condition)`
3. `.map( ... ) //will have access to second result)`
4. `.subscribe()`

Comment: not sure why the formatting was editted.  This was a single chain of code not a numbered serious of steps.

Comment: Thanks @MikeN it looks like this might work.  One question,  secondObservable emits a different type, what I really need is for it to added to an attribute of the firstObservable.  Is that possible?

Comment: flatmap functions get as input the result of the first observable, you can pass that result to the second observable getter and then propagate through to the result of that observable.

Comment: I updated the original ticket with where I am at so far.